# Problem with GRANT in Oracle 10

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, roles

I have the user admin who has admin privileges and default oracle XE user hr. User admin has created table CAR, role S and has granted to this role SELECT on table CAR. Then admin granted role S to user hr. But when hr tries to `select * from admin.car`, database gives an error that such table or view doesn't exist.
here is code:

```
create role S;
grant select on admin.car to S;
grant S to hr;
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a user logs into Oracle, all *default* roles are enabled, but non-default roles must be enabled with the SET ROLE statement:

```
SET ROLE S;
```

### Setting a role as DEFAULT Role

A default role means that the role is always enabled for the current session at logon. It also makes it no longer necessary to issue the `SET ROLE` statement. To set a role as a DEFAULT role, you need to issue the ALTER USER statement:

```
ALTER USER hr
DEFAULT ROLE S;
```

Reference:

- [Roles](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/roles.php)